# Kubebuilder Kustomize Shell

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize, kubernetes-operator, kubebuilder, k8s-cronjobber

Using the Kubebuilder initializer and I don't know to get the Kustomize shell. Whenever I try to install my operator onto minikube

I get the error below:

```
go: added sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kyaml v0.9.4
go: added sigs.k8s.io/structured-merge-diff/v3 v3.0.0
go: added sigs.k8s.io/yaml v1.2.0
/Users/mabeloza/Kubernetes/cronjob-tutorial/bin/kustomize build config/crd | kubectl apply -f -
bash: /Users/mabeloza/Kubernetes/cronjob-tutorial/bin/kustomize: No such file or directory
error: no objects passed to apply
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I am following the Kubebuilder Book tutorial (https://book.kubebuilder.io/quick-start.html).

I started off creating my project by initializing my kubebuilder project:
`kubebuilder init --domain tutorial.kubebuilder.io --repo tutorial.kubebuilder.io/project`

Then I created an API using the command:
`kubebuilder create api --group batch --version v1 --kind CronJob`

Am I missing a major step here?

Below are my generated directories and files:
[image]

Comment: Most likely the objects are not defined correctly in the kubernetes.yaml file. Please check the file once and confirm.

Comment: Where is the Kubernetes file, I am using the kubebuilder initializer. I updated the question with my available directories.

Comment: Use Kubectl(command line tool for kubernetes clusters) Commands below to access Yaml file.
Kubectl get pod my pod-o yaml. Refer to this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources).